# How to make first row as header in PySpark reading text file as Spark context

Tags: pyspark

The data frame what I get after reading text file in spark context

```
+----+---+------+
|  _1| _2|    _3|
+----+---+------+
|name|age|salary|
| sai| 25|  1000|
| bum| 30|  1500|
| che| 40|  null|
+----+---+------+
```

the dataframe I required is

```
+----+---+------+
|name|age|salary|
+----+---+------+
| sai| 25|  1000|
| bum| 30|  1500|
| che| 40|  null|
+----+---+------+
```

Here is the the code:

```
## from spark context
df_txt=spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/simple-2.txt")
df_txt1=df_txt.map(lambda x: x.split(" "))
ddf=df_txt1.toDF().show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spark csv reader to read your comma seperate file.

> For reading text file, you have to take first row as header and create a Seq of String and pass to toDF function. Also, remove first header to the rdd.

Note: Below code has written in spark scala. you can convert into lambda function to make it work in pyspark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/simple-2.txt")
val header = df.first()
val headerCol: Seq[String] = header.split(",").toList
val filteredRDD = df.filter(x=> x!= header)
val finaldf = filteredRDD.map( _.split(",")).map(w => (w(0),w(1),w(2))).toDF(headerCol: _*)
finaldf.show()
```

w(0),w(1),w(2) - you have to define fixed number of column from your file.

Comment: here is the final code in pyspark```
df_txt=spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/simple-2.txt")
df_txt_header=df_txt.first()
df_txt_header_list=df_txt_header.split(" ")
df_txt1=df_txt.filter(lambda x:x!=df_txt_header)## remove the header row
df_txt2=df_txt1.map(lambda x: x.split(" "))
ddf=df_txt2.toDF(schema=df_txt_header_list).show()```